# Stored Procedure vs Functions compilation and performance difference

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Recently I gave an inetrview in which the interviewer asked me to explain the most basic difference between Stored Procedure and UDF's.

I was able to recall a couple of differences as [listed here](http://sqlwithmanoj.wordpress.com/2011/09/21/stored-procedures-vs-functions-difference-between-sp-udf/) but he didn't accept any of them as the **BASIC** difference.

Answer according to him was that SP's are only compiled once while UDF's are compiled everytime they are called resulting in UDF's being considerably slower than stored procedure.

Now I have searched but couldn't get a clear cut answer whether this assertion is true.
Please verify this.

Comment: I know that estimated rows count for an UDF is 1 all the time...

Comment: They are wrong. UDFs aren't recompiled every time they are called. This is possible to prove a number of ways. e.g. trace (re)compile events in profiler, look at the plan caching DMVs. [My answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19884138/why-sql-functions-are-faster-than-udf/19891697#19891697) looks at the stack traces when executing UDFs multiple times. The overhead is during execution not compilation.

Comment: What sort of function - scalar or inline table-valued or multi-statement table-valued? The three are different types of objects with different execution mechanisms (the inline TVFs are inlined, for example :-).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@mhasan, thanks for referring to my blog-post in your question.

As far a I know **Stored Procedures** & **Functions** both have same behavior in terms of compilation & recompilation. Both are **not pre-compiled**. When you create either one of them they are just parsed and created, but not compiled. Both are compiled when they are executed for the first time. And they could be re-compiled automatically again if there is any change applied to them.

Execute following query after you create a new function:

```
SELECT objtype, cacheobjtype, usecounts, text 
FROM   sys.dm_exec_cached_plans AS p
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(p.plan_handle) AS t
WHERE  t.text LIKE '%YourNewFunctionName%'
```

You will see only one record, which is the Compiled plan of for this query itself, i.e. an Adhoc Object-Type.

After executing the function rre-execute this query again. You will see more records including the Compiled plan of the Function, which has an Object-Type of Proc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks manaoj bhai.. I have bookmarked your blog...will be learning a lot from there.

Answer (score 5):

That's a odd statement and as far I know UDF and SP are compiled (and recompiled when it changes) alike. It appear you interviewer mixed UDF with dynamic (non parametric) queries. If someone find a slight info to sustain that argument please report it.

Comment: To add, yep Scalar UDF can be slow and a good lecture about it is this  article and the followed discussion. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/91724/

Answer (score 4):

Jean is correct they are definitely compiled once.

Following query will give you the procedure cache and include useful metrics such as execution count, reads, etc:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 DB_NAME(qt.dbid)                                         AS DB,
                OBJECT_NAME(qt.objectid, qt.dbid)                        AS 'object_name',
                qs.total_worker_time,
                qs.execution_count,
                qs.total_logical_reads,
                plan_generation_num,
                SUBSTRING(qt.text, ( qs.statement_start_offset / 2 ) + 1, 
                                    ( ( CASE statement_end_offset
                                            WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(qt.text)
                                            ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
                                            END - qs.statement_start_offset ) / 2 ) + 1) AS 'query'
FROM   sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
       CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS qt
       LEFT JOIN sys.objects o
         ON o.object_id = qt.objectid
WHERE  qs.execution_count > 0
       AND DATEDIFF(Second, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) > 0
       AND DATEDIFF(Minute, qs.creation_time, GETDATE()) > 0
ORDER  BY /*Sort functions first*/
          CASE
            WHEN o.type_desc LIKE '%FUNCTION' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END,
          qs.execution_count DESC
```

In the report I am able to see functions with an execution count higher than 1. In other words the existing execution plan is reused. Same behavior as with stored procedures.